# In view how alter filter options with hook_views_pre_view

Tags: php, drupal, filter, view, hook

I have one filter with options (taxonomy), and I want delete options (if they are too old).

[image: My field]

How I can `hook_views_pre_view`?

I see that http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/how-alter-views-exposed-filter-allowed-value-list but it doesn't work because I don't have index 'value' (probably because I use a select).

Comment: please post your relevant code.  your question as it stands doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand using `hook_form_alter` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`. Inside those hooks you can get to your filter and modify the options of your select. An exemple would be :

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == 'my_form_id'){
      $my_options = array('key' => 'value');
      $form['my_field']['#options'] = $my_options;
   }

}
```